# Jquery add li class active

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Need add class to li

admin.tpl:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
<li><a href="admin.php">{"_MENUINFO"|lang}</a></li>
<li><a href="admin.php?site=ban_add">{"_ADDBAN"|lang}</a></li>
<li><a href="admin.php?site=ban_add_online">{"_ADDBANONLINE"|lang}</a></li>
</ul>
```

**if example.com/admin.php need**

```
<li class="active"><a href="admin.php">{"_MENUINFO"|lang}</a></li>
<li><a href="admin.php?site=ban_add">{"_ADDBAN"|lang}</a></li>
<li><a href="admin.php?site=ban_add_online">{"_ADDBANONLINE"|lang}</a></li>
```

**example.com/admin.php?site=ban_add**

```
<li><a href="admin.php">{"_MENUINFO"|lang}</a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="admin.php?site=ban_add">{"_ADDBAN"|lang}</a></li>
<li><a href="admin.php?site=ban_add_online">{"_ADDBANONLINE"|lang}</a></li>
```

end etc..
Please help!

Does not work

```
<li class="<?php if ($page=="admin.php") echo "active"?>">
```

Comment: what is the complete url? You can check the current href if it matches the href on your link. But you'll probably need to split the current href at a certain point. Don't know where unless you provide this, or at least the part of the string before admin.php

Comment: @user3008011 have you seen my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this **JQUERY**

first give the `id`  to your `ul`

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav_tabs">
```

then use jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('ul#nav_tabs li a').each(function(index, element) {
        var li = $(element).attr('href');
        $(element).parent().removeClass("active");   
       var filename = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

        if(filename==li)
        {
                $(element).parent().addClass("active"); 
        }

    });
});
```

also you can use **PHP** as

```
<?php
$my_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$page = substr($my_url, strrpos($my_url, '/') + 1)
?>

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav_tabs">
    <li <?php if($page=="admin.php") echo 'class="active"'; ?>><a href="admin.php">{"_MENUINFO"|lang}</a></li>
    <li <?php if($page=="admin.php?site=ban_add") echo 'class="active"'; ?>><a href="admin.php?site=ban_add">{"_ADDBAN"|lang}</a></li>
    <li <?php if($page=="admin.php?site=ban_add_online") echo 'class="active"'; ?>><a href="admin.php?site=ban_add_online">{"_ADDBANONLINE"|lang}</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: VERY BIG THANKS, JQUERY CODE WORK!!

Answer (score 1):

On click on link page will refresh then you can use php GET to get page name and set active class on li as below :

```
<?php

if (isset($_GET['site'])) {
    switch ($_GET['site']) {
        case 'ban_add':
            $activeClass1 = 'active';
            break;
        case 'ban_add_online':
            $activeClass2 = 'active';
            break;
        default:
            $activeClass = 'active';
            break;
    }
}
?>

<li class="<?php echo $activeClass; ?>"><a href="admin.php" >{"_MENUINFO"|lang}</a></li>
<li class="<?php echo $activeClass1; ?>"><a href="admin.php?site=ban_add">{"_ADDBAN"|lang}</a></li>
<li class="<?php echo $activeClass2; ?>"><a href="admin.php?site=ban_add_online">{"_ADDBANONLINE"|lang}</a></li>
```

Comment: Have u tried add script in admin.php and replace your li code with my code?

Comment: links a lot and I need a simple solution

Answer (score 1):

In document ready of jquery write this code. whenever page loads get the url and add class active to corresponding li tag.

```
$(function(){
    var pathName = location.pathname;
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="' + pathName + '"]').closest('li').addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: can write the complete code? I have no skills in script

Answer (score 1):

I would generate the list dynamically server-side and add a class to the `li` element that it's descendant `a`'s `href` matches with the current URL. This also makes your markup tidy and more maintainable.

Using JavaScript you can use the `.filter()` method:

```
$(function() {
   $('.nav-tabs a').filter(function() {
      return this.href === document.URL;
   }).closest('li').addClass('active');
})
```

Comment: how to connect this script?

Comment: @user3239481 By using `script` tags?

Comment: I paste this function to js file end wrote to <head></head>