# How to active tab on click in jquery

Tags: php, jquery, css

I want to add class active by clicking on `li` elements for that I have used jquery but it is not working. Here is the jquery

```
$('ul li a').click(function(){
$('ul li.active').removeClass('active');
$('ul li').addClass('active');
});
```

and here is my html,php code

```
<nav class="primary navbar navbar-default">
<ul class="term_list nav navbar-nav">

<li class="active"><a href="javascript:;" class="selected" data-filter="*">ALL</a></li>
<?php
foreach($terms as $k=>$tv) : 
$termname = strtolower($tv->name);
$termname = str_replace(' ', '-', $termname);
?>
<li class="">
<a href="javascript:;" data-filter=".<?php echo $termname;?>"><?php echo $tv->name;?></a></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</nav>
```

I am new in jquery. Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jquery add li class active](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21477563/jquery-add-li-class-active)

Answer (score 6):

`$('ul li').addClass('active')` adds the active class to *all* `li`.

Since you click a `a` tag, you want its `li` parent to get the active class, so :

`$(this).parent().addClass('active')` should work.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('ul li a').click(function(){
     $('ul li').removeClass('active');
     $(this).parent().addClass('active');
});
```